# Why not make a wikipedia-style history instead of protected questions or duplicated

Tags: feature-request

Why not make a wikipedia-style history instead of protected questions or duplicated who a "master" will do in representation of StackExchande.

Comment: How exactly would mimicking Wikipedia prevent duplicates?

Comment: How would they StackExchande it?

Answer (score 3):

Stack Exchange does have an edit history for all posts. It also has a "protected" feature, [much like Wikipedia also does](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Protection_policy).

These features both serve separate purposes, both on Stack Exchange and Wikipedia.

An edit history is good for auditing changes made to a post, and optionally rolling them back.

Protecting a question is good for preventing large amounts of bad content being added. A similar feature of locking a post is also useful for stopping edit wars over specific content.